# NameError: name 'Login' is not defined, functions

Tags: python

i am a beginner at python, when trying to make a function to sign in and register, it keeps giving me the error "NameError: name 'Login' is not defined" and or NameError: name 'Register' is not defined, also if you see anything i could improve upon please let me know

```
print('Banking app')


start = input('Login or Register?')

# if the user wants to log in 
if start == "Login":
     Login()

def Login(self, start):
    pass
    userName = input("Enter your username: ")
    passWord = input("Enter your password: ")

    #checking for the account 
    with open('Users.txt') as f:
        if userName and passWord in f.read():
            print('UserFound')
            accountFound = True
        else:
            print("Account not found ")
            accountFound = False



if start == "Register":
    Register()

#if user wants to make a account 
def Register(self, start):
    pass
    newUser = input("Enter your desired user: ")
    newPass = input("Enter your desired password: ")

    f = open('Users.txt', 'a')
    f.write(newUser)
    f.write(newPass)
    f.close()
```

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the Login() function before you call it， and the same for the Register function.

example:

```
def Login():
    pass

if start == "Login":
    Login()
```